# Can I enable/disable J2EE sessions in application.cfc?

Tags: session, coldfusion

If there is a way to enable/disable J2EE sessions in application.cfc as opposed to coldfusion 11 administrator, I cant find it.

administrator > Server Settings > Memory Variables > Use J2EE session variable

The reason I ask is that I want to be able to turn them on/off per folder, for testing.  I'm having trouble with sessions being lost.  I found that turning the j2ee alleviates much of the problem, but I cant tell if it is fully solved.

Comment: Not based on any official documentation, but I am guessing it is not possible.  Normally, sessions can be shared by multiple applications. I imagine having different apps with different settings would break that ..

Comment: You can turn off session management entirely. See https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-session-variables.html and https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-a-b/cfapplication.html

Comment: Sounds like they are asking about toggling J2EE sessions specifically - not disabling session management entirely.

Comment: What if session management was set to use cookies only, then htaccess/web.config was made to not set those `JSESSIONID` cookies?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the whole answer, but you can suppress the `JSESSIONID` cookie creation with web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="Remove JSESSIONID Cookie">
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="JSESSIONID*" negate="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
                    <conditions>
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
             </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

An even easier way is to set this in your application.cfc `OnRequestStart` (also stops the cookie's creation):

```
<cfcookie name="JSESSIONID" expires="now">
```

The missing piece is the knowledge of whether or not J2EE sessions require that cookie to operate.